# invalid syntax when trying to install pip

Tags: python

i'm trying to install this package called 'exceptions' in command prompt for Python, yet all i get is "invalid syntax". what seems to be the issue? i tried things like

```
pip18 install exceptions (i'm using version 18 of pip)
pip -m install exceptions
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OB4gN.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbwFA.png)

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what this 'exceptions' package is? Where did you learn of existence?

Answer (score 1):

The `pip` command isn't a python statement, it's a command like `python` and so it should be entered at the `c:\Users\L31308>` prompt.

`pip install exceptions` looks right, but unfortunately there doesn't appear to be an `exceptions` module to be installed. The packages are normally stored on the PyPI web site, sometimes referred to as "the cheese shop".

Perhaps if you could explain why you want to import this module and what it's supposed to do we might be able to find a fuller answer for you.

Comment: hi, i've tried that and i get this: Collecting exceptions Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement exceptions (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for exceptions

Comment: i want to import this module as i want to run my python project, and the error i am getting is that "there is no module named exceptions", hence i am trying to import exceptions

Comment: Who told you you required this `exceptions` module?